# Erro ao retornar dados do banco php + mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou Preenchendo o select com dados do banco ele chega até a parte do select na tabela bairros e retorna os ids da cidade porém ele não entra no loop da tabela clientes onde busca o ID_UF e caso eu coloque um id existente direto no where ele retorna o registro mas três repetidos,alguem sabe o que pode ser?

```
<select id="uf" name="uf" onchange="carrega(this.value)"; class="selectoso">
    <option value="0" >UF</option>
    <?php

    $querya = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID_ENDERECO FROM pessoas WHERE TIPO='Anfitriao'");
    while($resultadoa = mysqli_fetch_array($querya))
    {

        $retornaidEndereco = $resultadoa['ID_ENDERECO'];
        $queryb = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT  ID_BAIRRO  FROM enderecos WHERE ID_ENDERECO='.$retornaidEndereco.'");
        while($resultadob = mysqli_fetch_array($queryb))
        {
            $retornaidBai = $resultadob['ID_BAIRRO'];


            $queryc = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ID_CIDADE FROM bairros WHERE ID_BAIRRO='.$retornaidBai.'");
            while($resultadoc = mysqli_fetch_array($queryc))
            {

                $retornaidCid = $resultadoc['ID_CIDADE'];


                $queryd = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ID_UF FROM cidades WHERE ID_CIDADE='.$retornaidCid.'");


                while($resultadod = mysqli_fetch_array($queryd))
                {


                    $retornaidUF = $resultadod['ID_UF'];

                    echo '<option >'.$retornaidUF.'</option>';

                }
            }

        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenho algumas sugestões que voce terá q analisar baseado no que voce esta fazendo e analisando o seu banco:

1. o ID_CIDADE é uma chave primaria? Se ela esta se repetindo pode ser a causa das diversas linhas com o mesmo numero na chave;
2. supondo que a cidade possui apenas um UF e a sua busca deve retornar apenas uma linha pois o id deve ser unico, não é necessario iterar esse valor (foreach);
3. Ja pensou na possibilidade de utilizar um INNER JOIN em sua busca? me parece mais funcional doque as inumeras requisições ao banco de dados para trazer um só elemento, experimente essa query:

   ```
   SELECT cid.ID_UF from pessoas pes 
   INNER JOIN enderecos ende 
   INNER JOIN bairros bai 
   INNER JOIN cidades cid 
   where pes.TIPO = 'anfitriao' 
   and ende.ID_ENDERECO = pes.ID_ENDERECO  
   and bai.ID_BAIRRO = ende.ID_BAIRRO 
   and cid.ID_CIDADE = bai.ID_CIDADE;
   ```

Comment: Deu certo obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Se você que comparar as suas tabelas a fim de trazer tudo dentro `select` portanto irei lhe mostrar um código em `MYSQL` utilizando cláusula `JOIN` que basicamente, une / concatena tabelas

Tente utilizar este select dentro de um While e me retorne um feedback na minha resposta para saber qual foi o resultado.

```
<select id="uf" name="uf" onchange="carrega(this.value)"; class="selectoso">
       <option></option>
       <option value="0">UF</option>

    <?php

       $query = "SELECT * FROM A.id_endereco, A.tipo, B.id_bairro, C.id_cidade, D.id_uf FROM pessoa A"
           . " LEFT OUTER JOIN endereco B ON (A.id_endereco = B.id_endereco)"
           . " LEFT OUTER JOIN bairro C ON (B.id_endereco = C.id_endereco)"
           . " LEFT OUTER JOIN cidade D ON (C.id_endereco = D.id_cidade) WHERE A.tipo = 'Anfitrião' ;

       $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $query);

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['id_uf'].'">'.$row['id_uf'].'</option>';
       }

    ?>
</select>
```

Atente-se que o seu select possui 4 `while` e 4 `selects` com `querys` portanto para apenas um `select` você deve ter apenas um `while` e uma `query`. Entende ? E sempre que fizer um `<option> dentro de um bloco de`PHP`você deve colocar um`value`também assim como fez nesta linha`UF`Pois assim que for selecionado`UF`irá ser inserido no banco de dados o valor 0. E no código que fiz acima eu indiquei que o`value`do``é o próprio`id_uf`você pode alterar para o que quiser. Caso o código acima não funcione, utilize o debaixo com`INNER JOIN` e me de um feedback do que será o seu resultado.

```
<select id="uf" name="uf" onchange="carrega(this.value)"; class="selectoso">
       <option></option>
       <option value="0">UF</option>

    <?php

       $query = "SELECT * FROM pessoas A
             . " INNER JOIN enderecos B"
             . " INNER JOIN bairros C" 
             . " INNER JOIN cidades D WHERE A.tipo = 'Anfitriao'" 
             . " AND B.id_endereco = A.id_endereco" 
             . " AND C.id_bairro = B.id_bairro" 
             . " AND D.id_cidade = C.id_cidade";

       $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $query);

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['id_uf'].'">'.$row['id_uf'].'</option>';
       }

    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos que ajudaram!